# Sorting so that x matches y in data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, reindex

I have two columns in a single data frame, `ID_exp` and `ID_off`. I want the order in `ID_exp` to match `ID_off`. From what I've read I need to reindex rows to get this to work. Since I can't simply reindex by ascending/descending, it seems like I need a specific while loop to do it.

My general idea is something along the lines of:

```
x = 1
while x in ID_off < y in ID_exp #basically i want it to iterate through all the terms in ID_off 
if x == y:
continue to next row
x = x+1 #I'm not sure if I need to update index at this point?
if x =/= y:
#we go through y until we find x = y then reindex rows so x = y then start over (either at beginning or next value)
x = x+1 #I think this is how you re-index in python? this is how I did it in matlab
else
#we keep x in the same place and rename y to Na
#then we continue this until all values in ID_off have been sorted
df = df_new #rename df something new maybe to avoid confusion???
return df_new
```

To clarify, I want my data frame to be indexed such that values in `ID_off = ID_exp` (unless `ID_exp` doesn't have the value, since `ID_off` is longer than `ID_exp`, in which case it's just Na).

I hope this is enough info to explain my problem. I apologize for not having a better base for the starting code. Turning conceptual ideas into practical code is something I'm working on getting better at.

EDIT: PURPOSE/EXAMPLE EXPLAINED
So orginally ID_off was not in the same data frame as ID_exp -- I added ID_off to the data frame so that it would be easier (?) to organize. ID_exp is the sample ID for scientific experimental data I took and each row has sample specific data. ID_off is the order my data needs to be in so that I can input it into the company official data frame. My data is out of order relative to ID_off because when I was going through the samples, I was just doing it in the order the samples were given to me lol.

Using the alphabet, an example dataset would look like this

```
ID_exp = [A, C, Z, X, J, O, P, Y, E, W, Q, L]
ID_off = [C, Z, J, O, Y, B, A, W, L, Q, E, X, P, B, V, M, R]
```

(ID_off is longer because I haven't collected data from all the samples yet so hence the "Na" option if there just isn't data for that sample yet.)

And then the final product would be arranged something like this

```
ID_exp = [C, Z, J, O, Y, Na, A, W, L, Q, E, X, P, Na, Na, Na]
ID_off = [C, Z, J, O, Y, B, A, W, L, Q, E, X, P, V, M, R]
```

I hope this explains it better! I can try to come up with a different dataset if it's still not clear.

Comment: A [mre] never hurts: [edit] your question to include a very small subset of the dataframe as it is now (possibly with only the `x` and `y` columns), and what the desired result would look like.

Comment: If you add some example data, like @kraigolas suggests, perhaps it will be clear from the data why you're tring to sort one column separately from another, but it would probably help to explain what you're trying to achieve with it.

Comment: Is the OP asking to do an outer join of two columns and insert NA where data is missing? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @MYousefi Hi! Not quite but close! I'm trying to organize a data set based on one column (and then adding Na where data is missing).

Comment: @Kraigolas I added some sample data/examples and my goal with this code if that helps understand my question better :D

Answer (score 0):

If `ID_off` is just one column, then you can just [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) it: your goal is to make it the same as `ID_exp` which is redundant. However, if `ID_off` and `ID_exp` are associated with different dataframes, then you should use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the index of each dataframe to `ID_off` and `ID_exp`, respectively, and then use [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join the two dataframes. `join` will align the two dataframes on the same index.